# Edit Images Within Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can someone let me know if it's possible to edit images within joomla? I would like to be able to crop, annotate, etc an image within joomla. The only way I can see it's possible would to be to completely delete the image and upload the re-edited image - which would be painful, as I have so many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Online editing

You can use an extension like [JCE Image Manager Extended](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/component/zoo/item/image-manager-extended-4).

> Image Manager Extended adds to the power and ease of use of the Image
> Manager with options for resizing and thumbnailing images on upload,
> quick and easy image popup creation, a unique Thumbnail Editor and an
> Image Editor.

The image editor is fairly powerful, and includes functions like Resize, Crop and Rotate, plus a few image effects.

***Note that this is a subscription based extension.***

### Downloading images

In cases where I have to edit many images in Joomla, I usually download the entire **/images/** folder, edit the files locally using a real image editor, and then upload the files again, replacing the existing images.

If you have cPanel access, you can compress the entire folder, since it's a lot faster to download a single (large) file than hundreds or thousands of small image files. Then compress the images again when you're ready to upload the, and unpack everything on your server.

*<sup>Disclaimer: I am not in any way affiliated with JCE or joomlacontenteditor.net.</sup>*

Comment: Thanks for responding. Where can I find the image editor ? Thanks

Comment: @Carltonp https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/component/zoo/item/image-manager-extended-4